# Abusing comma operator to curry function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, comma-operator

In some languages, parentheses can be omitted in calling a function.

```
frobnicate foo, bar, baz, qux
```

Let's see if we can bring that, or something like it, into C++. This almost definitely implies abusing the comma operator, but, as far as I can tell, there's no way to extend arbitrary types to have an overloaded comma operator. So something like a proxy currier type could work.

```
comma_curry(frobnicate), foo, bar, baz, qux;
```

`comma_curry` (I'm not good with coming up with names) would probably be some kind of incremental currier whose comma operator takes one argument at a time. Ideally, I'd like this to have perfect forwarding semantics, such that it would be no different from simply invoking `frobnicate` outright.

```
frobnicate(foo, bar, baz, qux);
```

Especially if some of the arguments themselves are function calls, which may return prvalues.

```
frobnicate(foo(), bar, baz(), qux);
```

I've played around and come up with [a non-working example](https://godbolt.org/z/bPbpNp), using some helper code copied from another post. Anyone got some good or better ideas?

Comment: Love your idea and I even think you could extend all types using template comma operator. Of course you would have to put it in namespace to avoid strange behaviour

Comment: IMO, domain specific language (DSL) mini-languages always end in tragedy. Your example doesn't use [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), wouldn't that simplify things?

Comment: I had considered it, but bound functions don't get inlined. Also, this question is explictly tagged with `abuse`, so this is really just for fun.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, all of this is quite trivial to do with normal function arguments.

**I do not recommend using comma operator unless for learning and toy examples. Don't put this in production code.**

But using the comma operator can also be fun for incremental and re-currying. Here's a working example:

```
template<typename F, typename... Curry>
struct comma_curry {
    template<typename... C>
    explicit comma_curry(F function, C&&... c) noexcept :
       function(std::move(function)), curry{std::forward<C>(c)...} {}

    template<typename T>
    friend auto operator,(comma_curry&& self, T&& arg) -> comma_curry<F, Curry..., std::decay_t<T>> {
        return std::apply([&](auto&&... curry) {
            return comma_curry<F, Curry..., std::decay_t<T>>(std::move(self.function), std::forward<decltype(curry)>(curry)..., std::forward<T>(arg));
        }, std::move(self.curry));
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const& -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::apply([&](auto&&... curry) -> decltype(auto) {
            return function(std::forward<decltype(curry)>(curry)..., std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }, curry);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) && -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::apply([&](auto&&... curry) -> decltype(auto) {
            return std::move(function)(std::forward<decltype(curry)>(curry)..., std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }, std::move(curry));
    }

private:
    // [[no_unique_address]]
    F function;

    // [[no_unique_address]]
    std::tuple<Curry...> curry;
};
```

It supports currying references through `std::ref` and supports currying move only types.

It can be used like this:

```
int main() {
    auto function = [](int& i, double, std::unique_ptr<int>, std::tuple<int>) {
        std::cout << "Called! i value: " << i << std::endl;
    };

    int number = 1;

    // Reference arguments are sent using std::ref
    auto curried = (comma_curry(function), std::ref(number), 1.5);
    curried(std::make_unique<int>(), std::tuple{1});

    number = 42;
    auto recurried = (std::move(curried), std::make_unique<int>(), std::tuple{1});

    // We curried a std::unique_ptr, our function is a one time call
    // Since it's a one time call and destroy itself in the calling,
    // it must be moved
    std::move(recurried)();
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/PJu_SC)

Comment: I am loving this. But then what if `F` is a plain function pointer type?

Comment: @MonatheMonad see my edits. It's an old habit to use inheritance for EBO

Comment: I wonder why the comma is even overloadable. I haven't seen such a thing elsewhere, so far.

Comment: @MonatheMonad honestly I don't know either. I just know it makes life harder for those who write metaprogram.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gist of my idea how it can be done. Mind it is for one-arg functions only but can easily be extended for currying. I use tag type to make sure right overload is chosen:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

void print_thing(int a) {
}

struct go_t{} go; 

template<class F>
auto operator,(go_t, F f) {
  return [a=std::move(f)](const auto& b) {
    return a(b);
  };
}

template<class T>
auto operator,(const std::function<void(T)>& f, T&& t) {
    return f(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main() {
    // Make this happen!
    (go, print_thing, 42);
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I did in my non-working example, except I used a currier helper type instead. Mine kind of looks like it would work, but the complier treats it as UB (it poots out a `ud2` where the call would occur). I probably forwarded things incorrectly.